# Overriding- Why long is called instead of int

Tags: java

code 1:

```
class Tyre 
{
    public void front() throws RuntimeException 
    {
        System.out.println("Tire");
    }
    public void front(int a) 
    {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with int in tyre");
    }
    public void front(long a) 
    {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with long");
    }
}

class RadialTyre extends Tyre 
{
    public void front() 
{
        System.out.println("Radial Tire");
    }
    public void front(int a) 
    {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with int");
    }
}

class Test
{
      public static void main(String... args) 
      {
              Tyre t = new RadialTyre();
              int a = 10;
              t.front(a); 
      }
}
```

o/p for code1:-Radial Tire with int

code 2:-

```
class Tyre 
{
    public void front() throws RuntimeException 
    {
        System.out.println("Tire");
    }

    public void front(long a) 
    {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with long");
    }
}

class RadialTyre extends Tyre 
{
    public void front() 
{
        System.out.println("Radial Tire");
    }
    public void front(int a) 
    {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with int");
    }
}

class Test
{
      public static void main(String... args) 
      {
              Tyre t = new RadialTyre();
              int a = 10;
              t.front(a); 
      }
}
```

o/p for code2:- Radial Tire with long

Why in code1 child class int method is called while in code2 parent class long method is called? If this occurs due to widening then why in case1 widening does not take place? In code1 why a child class int method is called when an int method already exist in parent class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why in code1 child class int method is called while in code2 parent class long method is called?

Because you did **not** override, you ***overloaded***. Overloading is when the method name is the same but the signature is different (i.e. `long` parameter vs `int`).

Since you are referring to the type `Tyre` and not `RadialTyre`, and there is no override for that method `front`, it chooses the only one `Tyre` is aware of: the one which takes `long` parameter.

```
class RadialTyre extends Tyre {
    // This is an overLOAD, same method name but different parameter type
    public void front(long a) {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with int");
    }

    // This is an overRIDE, same method name with same signature
    public void front(int a) {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with long - override");
    }
}
```

> In code1 why a child class int method is called when an int method already exist in parent class?

That's how overriding works. If a class extends another class and overrides one or more of the superclass methods, those will get called.

Comment: Thanks for answering my 1st question. If Tyre is not aware of RadialTyre then why is the int method of RadialTyre getting executed instead of int method from Tyre class in code1? These int methods are definitely overrided.

Comment: @Snehai Answered the third question too. However, my primary language is not english and I've never heard of "widening". I'm reading about it on Wikipedia, it doesn't seem to be related with your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can refer this for understanding widening https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: Thank You for answering all questions